# Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code. Xcode 13 beta 5

Tags: xcode, build

Xcode 13 beta 5 build error.

- Tried clearing out derived data
- Clean build
- Restart
- Tried available StackOverflow solutions with similar title

Error log

```
2021-08-16 07:20:46.045 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2021-08-16 07:20:46.046 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:
2021-08-16 07:20:46.096 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2021-08-16 07:20:46.096 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:
2021-08-16 07:20:46.121 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2021-08-16 07:20:46.121 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:
2021-08-16 07:20:46.145 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2021-08-16 07:20:46.145 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:
2021-08-16 07:20:46.181 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2021-08-16 07:20:46.181 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:
2021-08-16 07:20:46.206 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2021-08-16 07:20:46.206 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:
2021-08-16 07:20:46.231 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2021-08-16 07:20:46.231 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:
2021-08-16 07:20:46.256 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2021-08-16 07:20:46.256 AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent[22021:116352] nil host used in call to allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:
Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: Hi, have you solved the issue somehow? I've run into the same error.

Comment: Xcode 13 RC fixed the issue for me.

Comment: same here brother need help?

Answer (score 2):

In my case It was an icon name that didn't exist (didn't have the asset), so I corrected the typo.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For people who come across this in the future, I fixed it by:

1. Nuking all of /Library/Developer (removing just DerivedData) didn't seem to be enough.
2. Restarting my Mac.
3. Reopening Xcode.